# Auto fill code from txt file to every html pages? import code from txt to all html pages via single code

Tags: html

I no longer want to always write the same code for every html file. Is there a way to make below code available on the all html pages.

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id="></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '');
    </script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
etc...
```

I mean, for example, copy code from head.txt on every html page. This will allow me to not write the same snippet of code on all the pages.

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: in shortcut - import code from txt to all html pages via single code

Comment: in the header no, the only way is using some server side programming language, or you can just copy this code every time ahah

Comment: if the code were not in the header, you could do it for example like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to understand, but I will try.

Documents are connected using

```
<link rel = "import">
```

:

```
<head>
   <link rel = "import" href = "/ path / to / imports / stuff.html">
</head>
```

The URL specified is the import location. To use import from another domain, its location must allow cross-domain resource sharing (CORS):

```
<! - Resources on other origins must be CORS-enabled. ->
<link rel = "import" href = "http://example.com/elements.html">
```

Note: browsers ignore repeated requests to the same URL. This means that from one address only one download will be performed no matter how many connections on the page

Comment: I think I will put a long code (google analytics, meta tags, favicon, css) in the head.txt and if there is no script to do+ that .txt imported the script into html.

Comment: yes, but html and css cant import to html via script.js

Comment: @windowswoed I updated the answer. Hope that helped.